# A square root computing turing machine

Tags: finite-automata, turing-machines, computation-theory, automata

I think i am close to this answer but still to confirm **can we create a turing machine(At least in Principle) which can work on real number computation and give exact results?**For example finding square root of an integer.**(whose output would be a real number)
My logic that we can't develop such a machine is that the real numbers are **uncountably infinite** and for uncountably infinite languages we can't create a turing machine.

Comment: Yet any given real number can be specified with countably many digits...

Comment: That's the point of confusion.The real numbers can be specified with countably many digits but the set of **all real numbers are uncountably infinite**.In language of automata,the language corresponding to real numbers is made up of uncountably infinite strings...

Comment: But you're never working on *all* real numbers at once. If you allow a countably long tape (maybe two-ended, trailing off the left for the input and off the right for the output), you could compute the square root of one number I reckon. You wouldn't stop in finitely many steps, but in countably many.

Comment: and when would the machine halt (if there is any) for example if the input to the machine is 5(11111 in unary notation)?

Comment: At time omega-naught of course :-)

Comment: I doubt your logic...That way we can say that the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem is solvable too by the turing machine....

Comment: No no, it's not an actual Turing machine, because it doesn't finish in *finite* time. You'd have to extend the notion to a "transfinite Turing machine". You can certainly *never* stop in finite time. I was just saying that you can probably do the next best thing though and stop in one-more-than-finite time.

Answer (score -1):

I think the Turing machine can be made if you put some restriction on Precision (i.e. answer up to 4 or 5 decimal place). Then it is possible. Otherwise I feel it can't be made.